# Issue in converting python file to an executable using cx_freeze

Tags: python, pyqt5, cx-freeze

I have been working on a python GUI based project using PyQt5. I am done with that and it runs perfectly on my PC but I want to make an executable out of it. So, i'm using `cx_freeze` to convert my python file to an executable. I have python version 3.5 and PyQt5.

When I build the script the build folder is made and when I run the executable it get the missing modules error as shown in the image attached.

Kindly, help me out i am stuck on this for ages now. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the modules in the same directory as the file you are converting to exe, then try it again.

Comment: from the site packages folder?

Comment: application_title = "YP Scrape" 
main_python_file = "ScrapeGUI.py" 

import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["bs4, urllib, requests"], "excludes": [""]}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

includes = ["atexit","re"]

setup(
        name = application_title,
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Sample cx_Freeze PyQt4 script",
        options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : includes }},
        executables = [Executable(main_python_file, base = base)])
This is my setup.py, is this fine?

Comment: Did you try doing it again with that setup file? What happened?